# Harvesting lightning from within the thunderstorm with a Faraday Cage

Tags: science-based, engineering, natural-resources, lightning

Lightning is abundant in some places in Earth. Attempts had been made it collect it. 
Laser triggered lightning below is the closest attempt.

[image]

By the time it reaches the ground most of the power is lost in light, sound and heat.

Would collecting electricity in lightning rich areas 
[image]

with a net supported by storm worthy balloon that don't pop to collect lightning branches before it becomes lightning or forms a visable bolt in the clouds?

Would enough netting in the clouds collecting electricity prevent lightning?

Would the discharge would be more frequent, voltage lower and the amperage higher?

[How much electricity would a good thunderstorm make if most of it could be collected before it turns into a lightning bolt?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/13638/invisable-lightning)

Comment: It is very cool, but this is more of a wild scheme than a wordlbuilding endeavor.  Check out halfbakery.com for lots more wild lightning harvesting schemes.  Including one with molten tungsten, if I recall.

Comment: @Willk this is a relativity a simple model and a is lightning more valuable in the cloud question.  No one has tried it since the kite on a key,

Comment: People did just that in Neil Gaiman's *Stardust*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The vast majority of the energy produced by your average lightning bolt is wasted by heating up and ionising the air around it. A large antenna array of fine conductors, placed on a suitable mountain/hilltop/slope, could route the charge to a battery or capacitor bank before any atmospheric breakdown occurs.

Comment: That is why you collect it before that happens in the clouds.

Comment: I doubt a chemical reaction (battery) can be fast enough to chase a lightning discharge...

Comment: @L.Dutch I mean, it should theoretically be possible but it can also be explained away by some unobtanium equivalent in the battery.

Comment: @L.Dutch I would use a crude electromagnet to turn a kinetic battery storage. By collecting it in the clouds the discharge will be less and total more than measured at the ground. The voltage should be lower with higher amps. No?

Comment: @Muze: Your higher amps will burn your coil. Remember electromagnets are inductors, which work by resisting changes in current

Comment: @nzaman Build a bigger one with fatter wires.

Comment: @Muze: Won't work. It's lightning. Once the onrush current has gone there's nothing left.